# Cannot select Custom Class for Table View Controller (UITableViewController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

Let me preface this by saying that I've already tried quitting and restarting Xcode, as well as deleting derived data for the project, to no avail. I'm at wits end right now.

Basically, I've created a custom `ViewController` class I want to use, but I cannot select it. In fact, using the Custom Class dropdown, I can only select the default `UITableViewController` class for my controller. The weird part is, it looks like the full list appears for a split second sometimes, before being replaced by the incorrect list with a single option. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Trying to select my class in the Identity Inspector Interface Builder]

I would really appreciate any ideas here. I'm not really sure what I could have done wrong, since I was following [this Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1) pretty much to the T.

For another scene in my project, which is just a plain view controller, I can select custom classes with no problems.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to inherit from UITableViewController class so basically the interface file (.h) should looks like that:

```
@interface YOURCLASSNAME : UITableViewController
```

Make sure you replace YOURCLASSNAME with your class name and you add UITableViewController and that should do the job.

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason, I had subclassed `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`. Working fine now :)

Comment: Another note, in case anyone else is running into this, I found that your class must be a direct subclass of UITableViewController. If the class is a subclass of a subclass of UITableViewController it doesn't show up in the list. As a workaround, you can change your class temporarily to subclass from UITableViewController, make the change in Interface Builder, then change the subclass back.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the swift file is defined as a UITableViewController and not as a UIViewController.