# The same issue but I cannot understand the answer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[Cannot select Custom Class for Table View Controller (UITableViewController)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563298/cannot-select-custom-class-for-table-view-controller-uitableviewcontroller)

Someone has asked the exactly I want to ask, but I do not understand which file should I add the "@interface YOURCLASSNAME : UITableViewController" into to make customer class for uitableview Controller?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: That answer is for Objective-C, not Swift. What does your custom class look like? Do you inherit from UITableViewController?

Comment: My custom class is a UIViewController class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just choose `File -> New -> File.. -> Source -> Cocoa Touch Class` from menu to create a new controller as your custom controller.

[image]

You can also reuse a already existed one.

(also notice the answer you refer use objc syntax, which differ from swift's)

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you understand the question of the asker to confirm that you are facing the same issue.

The issue that he was having was:

- He went to create a new class (For example: MainViewController) and chose 'UIViewController' as its superclass. Hence, his `MainViewController.h` file is declared as `@interface MainViewController : UIViewController`
- He wanted to assign this MainViewController to a custom UITableViewController on storyboard.
- He was not able to do so because the View Controller on storyboard that he dragged onto storyboard is of type `UITableViewController` whereas the MainViewController is of type `UIViewController`.
- So the solution is to change the superclass of MainViewController to UITableViewController:

Change this line :

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
```

into this:

```
@interface MainViewController : UITableViewController
```

Comment: Thank you for reply